# ¿Cómo recibir evento cuando llega nuevo correo?

Tags: php, laravel, imap, pop, idle

Actualmente uso el servicio de [SendGrid](https://sendgrid.com/docs/for-developers/parsing-email/setting-up-the-inbound-parse-webhook/) (capturo eventos de aperturas, recepción y click sin problemas), pero está orientado a envío  y no a recepción de correo, y la funcionalidad de la [API](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-php/issues/297) lleva 3 años en desarrollo y no acaba de salir, sin hablar de [otras](https://github.com/Ziggeo/php-sendgrid-parse) librerías que llevan 7 años sin actualizarse.

Mi idea era usar un correo corporativo con extensión propia (ahora mismo perteneciente a GMAIL) y usando [webklex/laravel-imap](https://github.com/Webklex/laravel-imap) conseguí sin problemas acceder a las bandejas y los correos y usar sus funcionalidades, pero necesitaría que la vista se actualizase en tiempo real al llegar un nuevo correo, y es aquí donde no consigo dar con la tecla.

Se que se puede con IMAP IDLE, pero no soy experto en esto y no consigo integrarlo, de momento solo tengo el siguiente código pero no es en tiempo real (tiene la limitación del sleep) y satura mucho el servidor.

```
RECONNECT:
// Connect to mailbox
$mailbox = new PhpImap\Mailbox('{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX', 'some@gmail.com', '*********', __DIR__);

CHECKMAILS:
// Search unseen (unread) mails
$mailsIds = $mailbox->searchMailbox('UNSEEN');

if(!$mailsIds) {
    echo 'Mailbox is empty. Waiting 60 seconds until next check...\n';
        sleep(60);

       // Clear IMAP cache to prevent high memory consumption
       $mailbox->imap('gc', array(IMAP_GC_ELT));

       if(!$mailbox->imap('ping')) {
              goto RECONNECT;
       }

       $mailbox_check = $mailbox->imap('check');

       if($mailbox_check->Recent > 0) {
              echo 'New emails arrived. Parsing them...\n';
              goto PARSEEMAILS;
       }
}

// Parse emails
PARSEEMAILS:
foreach($mailsIds as $mailId) {
       $mail = $mailbox->getMail($mailId);
   // Do something with $mail; eg. saving to database, sending autom. responses, ...

}
// Go back and check for new emails
goto CHECKMAILS;
```

En resumen, ¿Alguien tiene alguna idea de sólo recibir un evento a un socket o algo cuando reciba un email?

Comment: Tanto de una manera como de otra suelo encontrarme el mismo  problemas. El script puede fallar y detenerse (tanto con cli, como cron como montando un supervisor) y no notificar nada ni intentar reiniciarse. esto se puede dar por un fallo en memoria, conexión, blockeo de conexiones simultaneas, ....

Comment: El problema es que el coste elevado viene de tener que abrir la conexión cada momento, por lo que tirar un cron no soluciona nada, es mas si se superan los limites (en gmail 10 conexiones simultaneas) dará fallo.

Comment: La idea es hacer algo que pueda mantener la sesión activa en espera de notificaciones del IDLE de IMAP

Comment: Hay aspectos de tu implementación que no has aclarado, y lógicamente no podemos adivinar hasta que los comentas. Googlee un poco y [esto fue lo que encontré](https://pastebin.com/faXTpAWs), ojala te sirva. Saludos

Comment: @Marcos ¿Que no he aclarado?. respecto a tu código, tiene exactamente el mismo problema que el que yo postee. Si tienes un error o blockeo tu script dejara de funcionar sin informar nada y aparentemente estará bien, por lo que seguirá corriendo.